# Problema com hibernete e JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, back-end, jersey

É um WS REST, ele deveria devolver um doador, mais está dando uma exceção...

Console:

> ```
> set 22, 2016 3:37:15 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
> INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.1.Final}
> set 22, 2016 3:37:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
> INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
> set 22, 2016 3:37:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
> INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
> set 22, 2016 3:37:15 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
> INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
> set 22, 2016 3:37:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
> WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
> set 22, 2016 3:37:15 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
> GRAVE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>     at br.com.service.Relatorio.getGeral(Relatorio.java:34)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
>     at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
>     at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
>     at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:770)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:797)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
>     ... 44 more
> Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:229)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:183)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:78)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>     ... 55 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:217)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
>     ... 66 more    
> set 22, 2016 3:37:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
> GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [/Admin] threw exception
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>     at br.com.service.Relatorio.getGeral(Relatorio.java:34)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
>     at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
>     at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
>     at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:770)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:797)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
>     ... 44 more
> Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:229)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:183)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:78)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>     ... 55 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:217)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
>     ... 66 more    
> set 22, 2016 3:49:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
> INFORMAÇÕES: Reloading Context with name [/Admin] has started
> set 22, 2016 3:49:58 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
> INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
> set 22, 2016 3:49:58 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
> INFORMAÇÕES: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
>   br.com.service
> set 22, 2016 3:49:58 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
> INFORMAÇÕES: Root resource classes found:
>   class br.com.service.EmailService
>   class br.com.service.Relatorio
>   class br.com.service.Administrator
> set 22, 2016 3:49:58 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
> INFORMAÇÕES: No provider classes found.
> set 22, 2016 3:49:58 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
> INFORMAÇÕES: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 05:39 AM'
> set 22, 2016 3:49:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
> INFORMAÇÕES: Reloading Context with name [/Admin] is completed
> ```

O método relevante da classe Java:

```java
@GET
@Path("geral")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getGeral(@QueryParam("callback") String callback) {

    ArrayList<DoadorGeral> doadores = new ArrayList<DoadorGeral>();

    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("milicia");;
    EntityManager manager = null;

        try{
            manager = factory.createEntityManager();

            DoadorGeral doadorGeral = new DoadorGeral();

            doador doador = manager.find(doador.class, 1);

            doadorGeral.setId((doador.getId_doador()));
            doadorGeral.setNome(doador.getNome());
            doadorGeral.setCidade(doador.getNome_fantasia());
            doadorGeral.setData(DateUtils.getDate(doador.getData_cadastro()));
            doadorGeral.setEmail(doador.getEmail());
            doadorGeral.setDoacao(doador.getCpf());
            doadorGeral.setVisualization(DateUtils.getHoursAndDate());

            doadores.add(doadorGeral);

        }finally{
            manager.close();
            factory.close();
    }

    String json = new Gson().toJson(doadores);

    //return callback + "(" + json + ")";
    return json;
}
```

E o `persistence.xml`:

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

 <persistence-unit name="milicia">

   <!-- provedor/implementacao do JPA -->
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

   <!-- entidade mapeada -->
   <class>br.com.model.doador</class>

   <properties>
  <!-- dados da conexao -->
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" 
       value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.5/milicia" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="rdantas" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="l*5dsr$waFWWdf0521" />

   <!--  propriedades do hibernate -->
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

   </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Já pesquisei e achei várias soluções para isso, mas infelizmente não funciona nenhuma deles. Se eu executar uma classe com o método `main` ele funciona.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` - Ou seja, problema de classpath.

Comment: então, mas como pode estar com problema no classpath sendo que compila se eu rodar no metodo main? acredito que seja algo com o jersey, mas não sei oque é

Comment: Pode ser um problema de classpath ocasionado pela forma como você faz o deploy dele no Jersey. Quando você coloca a sua aplicação no Jersey, você sabe se o JAR do Connector do MySQL vai junto e é colocado no lugar correto?

Comment: Parece que não estava indo mesmo... coloquei o jar do mysql pelo maven  e funcionou normal. Vlw cara, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Você poderia mostrar os imports?